# Do the type of cleats matter?

Tags: football, equipment, technique

So, I've been playing soccer for a while now and when I play with flat soccer cleats (the one you wear when you play indoor soccer on cement or wooden floor) on a soccer field with grass, I don't play the same as when I use the cleats that  are supposed to be used on soccer fields. I can't dribble the same way and shoot the same so, I want to know if the type of shoes you wear (cleats or football flat shoes for indoor football) have anything to do when playing a match.

Comment: There's so many things to consider, condition of the pitch, weather conditions, personal feel...Some guidelines could be given I suppose, but still too opinion based and rather broad too.

Comment: @Don_Biglia - I think it's pretty clear cut. You wouldn't use indoor shoes on a muddy surface, and you certainly wouldn't use soft ground shoes on a dustbowl unless you want to roll your ankles.

Answer (score 4):

There are four main types of shoes that footballers commonly use.

- Soft ground shoes consist of a small number of long studs (usually 6 - 8 ) that penetrate wet or loose soil / mud to provide traction. These studs may be metal screw-ins. If used on firm ground, the studs won't dig in and the player is at risk of being unbalanced, leading to injuries such as sprained ankles.
- Firm ground shoes consist of a larger number (usually 10 - 15) small, moulded studs that distribute weight evenly. These boots grip into the grass on the surface of the pitch, but do not penetrate into soil. If used on soft ground, there will be a lack of traction, as the grass will come out of the ground and move under the shoe. If used on artificial turf or indoor, they will damage the surface, as well as provide a lack of grip due to reduced surface area.
- Turf shoes have numerous slightly-raised rubber studs or lugs that grip onto astro turf. They will typically mark wooden floors, so should not be used indoors. If used on natural turf, the grass will move too much underneath them, which may cause a loss of traction.
- Indoor shoes are made of non-marking gum rubber and are designed to grip on wooden floors. They will slide around on artificial and natural turf surfaces too much to be of use in those environments.

Also worth mentioning are blades and artificial turf shoes. These are less common, but artificial turf shoes are being used more regularly as more artificial turf pitches are being constructed in areas where grass does not grow easily, readily or cheaply.

I've sourced the information from personal experience and from [Kitbag's blog](http://blog.kitbag.com/which-football-boot-is-right-for-you/), [Pro-Direct Soccer](http://www.prodirectsoccer.com/information/ground-types.aspx) and [ebay's football boot buying guide](http://www.ebay.com.au/gds/What-Are-the-Different-Types-of-Soles-on-Football-Boots-/10000000177321722/g.html).